# Mat select drop down validation not working for the selected field Angular & Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-material2

I am working on Angular Material validation for the mat drop down. I have a drop down where if select the drop down value as **Text** will get text box (type = Text), the same if I select Number text box with (type = Number) will display, the same if I select date mat date field will display.

Here I want to have validation. if the field is empty I need to display error message but it is not working.

Here is my sample code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Name">Name of Assumption</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Assumption Name"
                    formControlName="assumptionName"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.assumptionName.errors }" minlength="1" maxlength="50">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.assumptionName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.assumptionName.errors.required">Name of Assumption is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-validation?file=src/app/app.component.html) code for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

As per your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-validation?file=src/app/app.component.html) example, you haven't call the function `initassumpationForm()`, which will create form controls for your form.

When I call that function from `contructor` or `ngOnInit`, it worked.